# Calling an instance method from a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class with 2 methods inside, the issue I am facing now is to figure out how I call the method inside the class into different module to do the task I want to perform. I can easily define the method as static with 5 arguments in it, but I don't want to do that way since I will adding more and more methods in the same class and I would like to inherit this class into another

```
class IDList(object):

def __init__(self, dsnDate, dsnExpel, dsnEOD, dsnIDay, SnapShot):
    self.dsnDate  = dsnDate
    self.dsnExpel = dsnExpel
    self.dsnEOD   = dsnEOD
    self.dsnIDay  = dsnIDay
    self.SnapShot = SnapShot

def get_partIDlist(self):
    prev_dt = self.dsnDate[self.dsnDate.bus_dt == prcs_dt]['prev_dt'].iloc[0]
    prev_partID = self.dsnExpel[self.dsnExpel['prcs_dt'] == prev_dt][self.dsnExpel.corp_cd == 3][self.dsnExpel.rltnshp_cd == 'PRIME_BROKERED'][['map_id', 'part_id']]
    part_id = self.dsnEOD[self.dsnEOD.bus_dt == prcs_dt][self.dsnEOD.run_cn == run_cn][self.dsnEOD.part_stat_cd == 'C'][self.dsnEOD.lvl_cd == 'A'][['map_id', 'part_id']]
    IDaypart_id = pd.DataFrame(columns=['map_id', 'part_id', 'wndw_hr_nb'])
    for snp in self.SnapShot:
        part_id_IDay = self.dsnIDay[self.dsnIDay.bus_dt == prcs_dt][self.dsnIDay.run_cn == run_cn][self.dsnIDay.part_stat_cd == 'C'][self.dsnIDay.lvl_cd == 'A'][self.dsnIDay.wndw_hr_nb == snp][['map_id', 'part_id']]         
        part_id_IDay['wndw_hr_nb'] = snp
        IDaypart_id = IDaypart_id.append(part_id_IDay)
    part_idList = pd.concat([part_id, part_id_IDay])
    return(part_idList)
```

Now on different module I tried to import this class and call the methods to perform the task. I have several of these methods that do different calculations. Here is how I am calling this

```
from pnl.exp.Engine import IDList
part_idList = IDList.get_partIDlist(var_bus_dt, part_rltnshp, cmpnt_chrg, iday_cmpnt_chrg, [8,11,12])
```

I am getting an error while I was calling this method this way, although I am passing a value to the argument python says 'missing'.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> TypeError: get_partIDlist() missing 1 required positional argument: 'SnapShot'
```

Comment: you are passing `list` for `Snapshot`?

Comment: [edit] your question and fix the indentation of the code in it.

Comment: Yes, it will loop through all the elements in a list if needed

Comment: @Martineau ---I copied the code from IDE I use, has the correct indentation when I copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are two/three ways to fix this:

1. The quick and not so smart way(you probably don't want to call a member function of an object of IDList)

   ```
   from pnl.exp.Engine import IDList
   idl = IDList(var_bus_dt, part_rltnshp, cmpnt_chrg, iday_cmpnt_chrg, [8,11,12])
   part_idList = idl.get_partIDlist()
   ```
2. The way you're expecting this to behave, as a static method:

   ```
   class IDList(object):  
   @staticmethod
   def get_partIDlist(dsnDate, dsnExpel, dsnEOD, dsnIDay, SnapShot):
       prev_dt = dsnDate[dsnDate.bus_dt == prcs_dt]['prev_dt'].iloc[0]
       prev_partID =dsnExpel[dsnExpel['prcs_dt'] == prev_dt][dsnExpel.corp_cd == 3][dsnExpel.rltnshp_cd == 'PRIME_BROKERED'][['map_id', 'part_id']]
       part_id =dsnEOD[dsnEOD.bus_dt == prcs_dt][dsnEOD.run_cn == run_cn][dsnEOD.part_stat_cd == 'C'][dsnEOD.lvl_cd == 'A'][['map_id', 'part_id']]
       IDaypart_id = pd.DataFrame(columns=['map_id', 'part_id', 'wndw_hr_nb'])
       for snp in SnapShot:
           part_id_IDay = dsnIDay[dsnIDay.bus_dt == prcs_dt][dsnIDay.run_cn == run_cn][dsnIDay.part_stat_cd == 'C'][dsnIDay.lvl_cd == 'A'][dsnIDay.wndw_hr_nb == snp][['map_id', 'part_id']]         
           part_id_IDay['wndw_hr_nb'] = snp
           IDaypart_id = IDaypart_id.append(part_id_IDay)
       part_idList = pd.concat([part_id, part_id_IDay])
       return(part_idList)

   from pnl.exp.Engine import IDList

   part_idList = IDList.get_partIDlist(var_bus_dt, part_rltnshp, cmpnt_chrg, iday_cmpnt_chrg, [8,11,12])
   ```
3. The IDList class isn't even doing anything, you can just define get_partIDlist() as a module-scope function in pnl.exp.Engine and change your import line to:

   ```
   from pnl.exp.Engine import get_partIDlist
   ```

Comment: @Anand I doubt that. You're passing parameters to a function ```def get_partIDlist(self)``` which only takes self. If you make it a static method that takes all the parameters, I can't imagine why you'd be getting any call-related errors. If you still have errors after making the method static, you have an error somewhere else that you haven't shown.

Comment: I have tried both ways before posting this question. The first method was throwing error   TypeError: get_partIDlist() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'dsnDate', 'dsnExpel', 'dsnEOD', 'dsnIDay', and 'SnapShot'    The second way you mentioned will works and I was doing it but I have several of those methods in my class (I just put only one in there due to space limitation ) and in future I want another class to inherit this one, hence static method is probably not a way to go for me although it works perfectly

Comment: Ok, well it's pretty much impossible to help you if you don't post all the code. It sounds to me like you've overridden get_partIDlist() in the code you haven't shown and you have conflicting signatures. Post the entire class and I'll edit.

Comment: @rpg711.....I have another method which is very similar to the one I showed here but need to pass different dataset into the argument given above. Your comment on overriding 'struck' me. I was indeed overriding self.SnapShot with SnpShot on the second method on which python was angry at. Thanks for pointing that out, fixed it. The first method you showed will work now